# Which Java structure better to use? I need good performance, non-fixed size, and ease to clone / copy

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, arraydeque

I'd like to have a data structure with a good performance which allows easy clone/copy from one structure to another. My flow looks like this:

- Take `list1`, full of objects.
- Iterate over the objects, create from each object several objects of the same type, and add them into `list2`.
- Erase all objects from `list1` and add all objects from `list2` into `list1`.
- Erase all objects from `list2`.

I'm stuck to choose a data structure, for the moment I use `ArrayDeque`, which is not very fast. The number of objects is not fixed, so maybe array is not a good choice.
Any advice please? Here is my code :

```
ArrayDeque<Obj> list1 = new ArrayDeque(),
list2 = new ArrayDeque();

// Iterate over list1 
// and add() objects into list2 

list1 = list2.clone();
list2.clear();
```

Thank you !

Comment: how many objects are you planning to store at a maximum?
Could your objects have version field on them so that you don't need to add and remove, but simply up the version once the object has been processed?

Comment: Why clone? Just flip the lists, e.g. `ArrayDeque<Obj> tmp = list1; list1 = list2; list2 = tmp; list2.clear();`

Comment: @diginoise not more than 1000 objects. Good idea about version, but no, to process for me means to create completely new objects of the same type.

Comment: *"I use ArrayDeque, which is not very fast"* `ArrayDeque` is fast. Why do you believe it is `ArrayDeque` that is the cause of your performance issue?

Comment: @Andreas what will be the benefits of flip over clone ?

Comment: @Andreas because array is faster. Unfortunately, array is not a good fit here.

Comment: @tkrishtop No copying of references. No creating of a new `ArrayDeque` object. No discarding of old `ArrayDeque` object, so nothing new to GC.

Comment: I don't see the need for all the back and forth.  Use a lambda to process every element in list1 and you're done.  All the better if you can use a parallelStream.

Comment: @duffymo to process for me means to create completely new objects of the same type.

Comment: Why?  Like I said, I see no reason for doing so.  Can you explain?  You have the list; you change the state of every object; you clone them; you put them back.  That's a lot of work to have list 1 end up with objects in the updated state.  No need for it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With 1000 objects you don't have to be too sophisticated unless this is performance critical or creation of each object of class `Obj` is a long process.

Assuming following (very noddy) immutable `Obj` class:

```
public static final class Obj {
    private String property;

    public Obj(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public Obj modify(String newProperty) {
        return new Obj(property + newProperty);
    }
}
```

Following code executes very quickly for 100k elements:

```
public static final int NUM_ELEMENTS = 100_000;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //init
    ArrayDeque<Obj> source = new ArrayDeque<>(NUM_ELEMENTS);
    ArrayDeque<Obj> destination = new ArrayDeque<>(NUM_ELEMENTS);

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++) {
        source.add(new Obj("" + i));
    }

    //modify
    source.stream()
            .map(obj -> obj.modify(" V2"))
            .forEach(obj -> destination.add(obj));

    source.clear();

    //print
    destination.stream()
            .forEach(obj -> System.out.println(obj.getProperty()));
}
```